# Dates on Chart Do Not Match Dates on Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, timeline

I am attempting to create a chart so that each Project has a name up the Y axis and the duration of each category is plotted across the x axis.

However, the duration and dates on my chart, X axis, do not match the dates recorded on my table.

For instance; The project name is in column 1b, with a start date of 05/01/2018 is in column 2 b, the duration for the start date category is 1 day which is recorded in cell 3b. Continuing on through several categories and their start date and duration's.

When I view this in the chart it seems that the horizontal bar chart lines up correctly to the dates on the x axis but eventually falls way short ogf the last category date.

EX:
Safe Auto ClaimIQ Bypass

- Bar chart does not match the last category date of 11/30/2018

[image: chart example]

Please help!

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1431145/edit) to provide sample data (and the corresponding chart) showing the problem clearly?

Comment: Your screenshot is way too small to see anything useful. Crop it to show more detail and include the underlying data.

Answer (score 0):

When plotting a Gantt chart like this, you need to make sure that the stacked horizontal data values are the duration units. Stacking date values on top of dates will produce nonsense.

In the below screenshot, the four series names are in column A. The plotted values are in column D. Note how only the duration in days are stacked on top of the start date.

[image]